# K means algorithm implementation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What columns do I have to consider while implementing K Means? I have 91 columns after pre processing. And also to how many columns do I have to apply K Means clustering ? Is it all of them or only a few to be considered ?

Comment: not much to help here, you need to provide more information about your problem.

Comment: I actually want to ask is it advisable to implement KMeans to all the columns or only a few columns ? There is no limit to number of columns I can perform the algo right ?

Comment: I don't know about your problem, because you didn't provide with any information about it. Alas I can't suggest a solution or a prefered algorithm for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually about trial and error. There is no straight way to say which columns are going to help you the most until you try and figure it by yourself.

but you can use **dimensionality reduction algorithms** like **PCA** to project data to a lower dimension without much data loss. It's a common approach and also helps with the speed of your clustering algorithm.